# After changing the hostname pi zero disappears

Tags: pi-zero, putty, raspberry-pi-os-buster

Pi zero
2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-lite
wpa_supplicant
ssh
heatsink
Highspeed 32 microsd card
Recommended power supply
headless (naturally)   changing password works ok
using putty to connect

works fine before changing the hostname - steady green light after rebooting  - lights on but nobody's home

What to do?

*EDIT(s)
Sorry for using an old metaphor. It means that there is the appearance of working but no other evidence.)

The light is on green which is normal for the pi zero when working. However, it does not appear on network scans and does not respond to attempts to log in. If the user name or the hostname is changed, the pi zero stops responding. Changing the password does not cause any problems.

Additionally, when loading the OS the files are modified and the ssh and configuration files disappear from the SD card as they should.

Additional information:
Installed an OS with a UI and still cannot connect. Will use a monitor and keyboard as soon as the HDMI cable arrives. Will add the results when I get a chance.

Comment: What on earth do you mean with "lights on but nobody's home", that is lacking substantial data describing the problem.

Comment: Using metaphors to describe technical problems is a bad idea. When you say nobody's home, does it mean pizza is not getting delivered, or even firemen cannot enter?

Comment: @dom it would appear you have lost access to the original account with which you used to post this question. Instead of creating a new account to try to edit this question could you please try to get access to your old account or seek to get your [accounts merged](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).